# MVC4 controller/route not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

my VisitsController:

```
public ActionResult Index(Visits visits, int? id)
{
    ....
    return View(v);
}
```

Here is my route config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}


Works: http://localhost:49225/Visits
Does not work: http://localhost:49225/Visits/123
```

What would the custom route be (and force it to be an integer)?

Comment: For http://localhost:49225/Visits/123 you'll need to create a new route, or use http://localhost:49225/Visits/Index/123

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:49225/Visits/Index/123 ??

Comment: @Husein yes and it works, thx, but I want localhost:49225/Visits/123 to work.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to have a similar access to resources that you would have if you implemented Web API project. Sort of REST-based access to data. That way you would have {controller}/{id} route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new route for that to work.

Currently, this will work:

```
/Visits/Index/123
```

I believe you need to add the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "VisitsDefault",
    url: "Visits/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Visits", action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This is assuming you have a modelbinder for Visits already.

Comment: Thx! I added the constraint and removed the optional parameter. NOTE to others, at least in the case, this must come before the default route.

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "VisitsForDate",
   url: "Visits/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Visits", action = "Index" },
   constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

Comment: Correct! Always order your routes from most specific to most general, because the routing engine will try to match all of them sequentially. Glad I could help.